# Use network interface to send data to GNURadio

Tags: linux, network-interface, fifo

### Shorter version

How can I make a network interface on Linux send and receive packets from a running process rather than a network device driver?

### Longer version

I'm planning as my bachelor thesis to build a custom wireless ad-hoc network (not 802.11, but using the IP protocol stack) on top of a couple of USRP N210 (Software Defined Radios made by Ettus) to communicate between two computers. The idea is to implement the link layer on GNURadio, using the USRPs to transmit and receive the radio signals.

[image: The protocol stack]

Ideally, I'd like the whole communication system to be **transparent** to the hosts, like if it was just another network connected to some interface (like eth0, etc). So I've been wondering if there is any way of creating a **network interface** (virt0 in the image) on Linux and make it communicate with GNURadio (that uses Python and C++) instead of the network device driver. The purpose of this is that the GNURadio environment can have access to the packets that need to be sent and forward them (after some processing) through the USRP to be received by the other host.  Would a pipe make it, since it's an inter-process communication?

[image: The need]

That's the first idea I got to achieve the transparency I was talking about. I've also thought of writing a dummy network driver to interface with GNURadio, but I'd like to evade this, given my lack of experience with device drivers. If you had any other idea, it would be welcome.

Comment: I'm not sure how your technical analysis is progressing but it's rather unclear what you're trying to do.  I would guess that you either need a service to handle the protocol exchange, or routing and NATing rules.  Without more analysis or clarifications, you will not find a generic answer.

Comment: Ok, I changed it a bit. Hope it's a bit clearer now :)

Comment: The drawing matches the description but you still provide no protocol or addressing details.  How does a GNURadio connection interact with TCP/IP?

Comment: I don't really need it to interact with TCP/IP. I want it to tunnel all information from the IP layer up as the ethernet and wifi link layers do

Comment: How?  You do not seem to be able to explain what you're trying to do after much insistance.  The drawings are all pretty nice but don't show **any** detail on how you plan to do it.  Would you broadcast all the packets no matter their origin and destination?  If so, wouldn't that triple the wireless bandwidth usage and double the Internet connection usage globally?  How do you expect to know where to direct the response you get (similarly to NATing)?

Comment: It would be a network for point-to-point communications, like if you had a 802.11 ad-hoc network between two computers, and nothing else. So there's no connection to the internet implied. I don't see where NATing would come on scene.

Comment: A 802.11 network is designed for TCP/IP communications with addresses and ports.  This way all the involved equipment, drivers, and tools can rely on that standard to know where to send the information and how to return the response to the right place.  You will need to specify how would your system know what needs to go on your magical ad-hoc network and what needs to go on another interface or through another driver.  Since that's your project's intent to show you know how to do it, then start writing those specs.

Comment: You show nice images of the TCP/IP model, but from the little information your provide, I doubt you know the difference between the different layers and how they interact together.  Please don't waste our time arguing and just give details if you hope to get any useful comment or answer.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, the OS takes care of which interface to use depending on the destination IP address of the data and the local routing table. I would configure a static IP on the 'virt0' interface of the two computers, with corresponding network and broadcast addresses.

Comment: Does this mean that what would be transmitted through `virt0` would be sent to a specific IP address and port?

Comment: Yes. I intend to be able to send an UDP stream from one host to the other

Comment: Anyway, I didn't come here to argue, neither to waste your time. It's clear I don't get to explain myself here, so I'll give it a better thougt in the next couple of days and then launch another post when I get a clearer picture. Thank you for your efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create network interfaces that can send and receive packets backed by some program (which, in your case, would be connected to GNU Radio in some way) using the **tun/tap** interface.

To quote from `Documentation/networking/tuntap.txt` in the kernel source:

> TUN/TAP provides packet reception and transmission for user space programs. 
>   It can be seen as a simple Point-to-Point or Ethernet device, which,
>   instead of receiving packets from physical media, receives them from 
>   user space program and instead of sending packets via physical media 
>   writes them to the user space program.
>
> In order to use the driver a program has to open `/dev/net/tun` and issue a
>   corresponding ioctl() to register a network device with the kernel. A network
>   device will appear as `tunXX` or `tapXX`, depending on the options chosen. When
>   the program closes the file descriptor, the network device and all
>   corresponding routes will disappear.
>
> Depending on the type of device chosen the userspace program has to read/write
>   IP packets (with tun) or ethernet frames (with tap). Which one is being used
>   depends on the flags given with the ioctl().
>
> The package from http://vtun.sourceforge.net/tun contains two simple examples
>   for how to use tun and tap devices. Both programs work like a bridge between
>   two network interfaces.
>
> `br_select.c` - bridge based on select system call.
>
> `br_sigio.c`  - bridge based on async io and SIGIO signal.
>
> However, the best example is VTun http://vtun.sourceforge.net

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003684/how-to-interface-with-the-linux-tun-driver) stackoverflow question. Lots of tutorials can be found with google.